# How to define macro for C project in autotools?

Tags: c, macros, autotools

How do I define macros on a per-project, or per file level in a C project using autotools?

Presently I have this: `mount_cpfs_CPPFLAGS = -DFUSE_USE_VERSION=28`, but I'm not sure that this is the "portable" way to define a C macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using generated header files with [`AC_DEFINE`](http://kambing.ui.ac.id/gnuftp/old-gnu/Manuals/autoconf-2.57/html_node/autoconf_82.html#SEC82).